# ASM symbolic constant behaviour

Tags: assembly

Consider the following code:

```
data segment
    v1 dw 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    v2 dw 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
    E equ v2
ends
```

E is 9, because E is v2 which represents the first value in the v2 array.

If I write it this way:

```
data segment
    v1 dw 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    v2 dw 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
    E equ v2/2
ends
```

I was expecting E to be 5 (10 divided by 2), but it is actually 6. I think it is 6 because now v2 means the array's offset, which is 12 (= 6 words).

I am using emu8086.

Could somebody explain me the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be pretty surprised to find that `E` is equal to 9 in the first example. That would be craziness. `E` should be 12, which is the offset of `v2` from the beginning of the data segment. You should go back and verify your results.

In any case, when you use `equ` in this way, you're working with offsets.

`equ` is a compile-time (okay, assembly-time, whatever) construct. As such, it can't *ever* access memory. Given your example:

```
v2 dw 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

There is no way (that I know of) to write an `equ` expression that references the contents stored at `v2`. That is, you can't have:

```
E equ (some expression that results in getting the value 10 from v2)
```

Never happen.

`equ` does offset arithmetic, only.